# What happened to Captain Marvel's cat?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel

Captain Marvel's cat, Goose, is a Flerken, and maybe one of the deadliest aliens the MCU’s ever seen. What happened to Goose after the events of *Captain Marvel*? Nick Fury has kept him in this office. But that kind of deadliest creature was never mentioned before in the MCU or in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*

Comment: @ZaidSyedMMd The cat later is not normal, as you can see in the post-credits scene. (The Flerken doesn't appear in the _mid-credits_ scene, but does in the _post_-credits scene. So stick around!)

Comment: Cat superhero?!! I'm sufficed with raccoon

Answer (score 3):

We finally got to see Goose again in *The Marvels*, the 2023 sequel to *Captain Marvel*. The movie explained that Goose, the adorable but deadly Flerken, had been living with Maria Rambeau, Carol Danvers’ best friend and Monica’s mother, after the events of *Captain Marvel*. However, when Maria’s cancer returned some time after the Blip, she asked Carol to take care of Goose.

Answer (score 1):

Goose seems to be the MCU's version of Chewie from the Captain Marvel comics. Chewie lives with Carol, so it's likely that Goose will pop up in future Captain Marvel films. He may not be in the next Avengers as he may have been wiped out by the snap.

Also, it makes sense for Fury to keep Goose's existence a secret. A creature containing a pocket universe is a useful tool and Fury shows genuine affection for him. Keeping him as a secret weapon but also keeping the softer side of himself secret, makes sense for Fury.

Comment: Fury just needs to keep Goose away from his remaining eye.